# Apache proxy: Accept client timeout but keep connection alive with back-end server

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, load-balancing, mod-proxy

We have an Apache 2.4 proxy in place between an app we're developing and a third-party app which does a lot intensive image rendering. We're basically using the proxy as a way to throttle connections going to the third-party app as to not overflow it, since it has a tendency to crumble under the pressure.

Currently, client requests coming from our app timeout after 2 minutes. Apache relays that timeout, closes its connection with the third-party app and then assigns a new connection to process. The problem is that the previous connection that was assigned is not and can not be interrupted with the third party/back-end server. Which means that as long as the third-party is busy, Apache will keep piling requests on top of it until the back-end server crashes.

My question: is it possible for Apache to accept a client timeout but keep the same connection open with the back-end server as long the latter hasn't sent a response?